# How to change the RAM reserved for video?

Tags: linux, memory, video, amd-ryzen

I just bought a couple of Lenovo laptops using vega8 but it has been found this comes with a fixed (I expect not) amount of 3GB reserved for the video.
Use of games or video related isn't the idea for these machines, so I wish to change the amount of RAM or change the video instead of reserved to shared.

Looking in Linux/windows for some way to achieve this but everything seems to be related to flashing the BIOS with a version that allows this.

Is there a patch or something like that to reconfigure the amount of video memory?